# 301/302 redirect from slash root to specific home page url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been asked by my client's SEO agency to perform a 302 redirect on the home page of their website to the more specific URL of the same page i.e. **(not the slash root version)**. This is a WordPress site running on Apache2 with .htaccess file in place. I need to achieve the following:

**Redirect from:**

```
http://www.example.com/
```

**302 redirect to:**

```
http://www.example.com/home/
```

**I thought I could do this:**

```
redirect 302 / http://www.example.com/home/
```

But of course this redirects everything to that url. So I guess I need some sort of regular expression but not sure how to produce the desired effect? Could anyone point me in the right direction? Any feedback greatly appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this line:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /home/
```

To make sure only root is redirected to `/home/`

Answer (score 5):

The `Redirect` directive uses prefix matching, so the rule mentioned in your question matches all URLs that start with `/`... i mean ALL. [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) should be used in this case:

> This directive is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular
>   expressions, instead of simple prefix matching.

So this is what you need to do:

```
RedirectMatch temp ^/$ /home/
```